# How do I add an internal style sheet (not inline) at run time in Angular?

Tags: css, angular, runtime

In my Angular 4 app, I have a page whose content is stored into a JSON (partly CSS definitions and partly HTML markup) at a certain URL on my server. So I've made a shell component to host the content in Angular.

For HTML, I had to use `<div [innerHTML]="my_html"></div>` in the template and `this.my_html = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(my_html);` in the script.

For CSS, I tried

1. `<style [innerHTML]="my_css"></style>`
2. `<style>{{my_css}}</style>`

with different combinations of sanitization but Angular 
always compromise the `<style>` element. In particular:

1. in this case it removes the element from the template but does'n append it to the head. The element just vanishes.
2. in this case it removes the element from the template and appends it to the head like this `<style>{%BLOCK%}</style>`. In other words, the element is useless.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I had to use jQuery `$('<style>').text(my_css).appendTo('head');` in the `ngOnInit()` handler, which works nicely, but doesn't feel... Angular.